# dropdown navbar does not close after it has been clicked

Tags: html, css, typescript

I have a navbar implemented using bootstrap but the problem is, the navbar can't close on its own after I click on a link. I need to drag my mouse pointer away from the navbar for it to close.

The project that I'm currently working on uses Typescript, which is not my forte but I'm still learning. Thank you!

UPDATE: Typescript is in the snippet

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { NavbarService } from '../services/navbar.service';
import { ResponsiveService } from '../services/responsive.service';
import { Router, Event, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  public isMobile: Boolean;
  constructor(
    public nav: NavbarService,
    private responsive: ResponsiveService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onResize();
    this.responsive.checkWidth();
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
  
  onResize() {
    this.responsive.getMobileStatus().subscribe((isMobile) => {
      this.isMobile = isMobile;
    });
  }
}
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(
    router: Router
  ) {
    router.events
          .pipe(filter((routerEvent: Event) => routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd))
          .subscribe(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 1vh 0;
  transition: 0.1s all ease-in;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #c1ae8d;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
  margin: 0 2vw;
  font-family: Work Sans;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 29px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}

.active {
  color: rgb(221, 221, 221) !important;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown {
  position: static;
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 300px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  display: block;
  transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
  background: none;
  color: #c1ae8d;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover,
.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-2:hover,
.btn-2:active,
.btn-2:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-2 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#" id="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Accessories
              </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu shadow-sm">
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/shop/category/Necklaces">Necklaces</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/shop/category/Bracelets-Anklets">Bracelets and Anklets</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/shop/category/Earrings">Earrings</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/shop/category/Rings">Rings</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/shop" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Shop All</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a routerLink="/jewelry-care" routerLinkActive="active">jewelry care</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a routerLink="/contact-us" routerLinkActive="active">contact us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a routerLink="/about-us" routerLinkActive="active">About Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <a>
      <button class="btn-2 mr-2" routerLink="/cart">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1200/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path
                    d="M8 1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.5 2.5V4h-5v-.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 8 1zm3.5 3v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-7 0V4H1v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h-3.5zM2 5h12v9a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V5z" />
                </svg>
              </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Where is the typescript

Comment: it is already updated sir @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

can't see the javascript code, but id recommend starting your debugging there.
the most common way to look at this issue is by looking at the code for the navbar-toggler button (looks like a hamburger) and making sure that when its clicked, it removes the css class responsible for keeping the navbar open, or simply force the navbar shut with javascript (display:none)

are there any errors displayed in your developpers console (f12) ?

finally i should recommend going with a vanilla navbar, especially if you're a beginner
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: it has already been updated with the typescript code and as for the errors, there are none